# Error while connecting to sftp using shell script

Tags: fedora, shell

I am getting following error while trying to connect to a sftp server:-

> ncftpput: cannot open
>   http://mydomain.com:
>   unknown host.

Code which I am using is as following:-

> > FTPU="username" # ftp login name
> >
> > FTPP="password" # ftp password
> >
> > FTPS="http://mydomain.com"#
> >     remote ftp server
>
> FTPF="/home" # remote ftp server
>   directory for $FTPU> & $FTPP
>
> > LOCALD="/localpath"
>
> ncftpput -m -u $FTPU -p $FTPP $FTPS
>   $FTPF $LOCALD

I am currently running this script on fedora 10...

thanks.....

Comment: If you try to connect to it using other methods (e.g. from within nautilus or with sftp) does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ncftpput is an FTP client that does not support SSH (see their [FAQs](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/faq.html)). Also, in your script you're providing an HTTP URL instead of just a server name. If mydomain.com actually runs an FTP server, try FTPS=mydomain.com instead.